# php webmoney перевод средств

Tags: php, webmoney

Необходимо автоматизированно переводить средства с кошелька **Webmoney**.
Пробовал использовать [эту библиотеку](https://github.com/baibaratsky/php-webmoney/wiki/X2). Подставил в код свои данные (`wmid`, путь к файлу ключей, номера кошельков и т.д.)
Выдаёт ошибку:

> "Payment error: create error step=14"

:(

Comment: А вы прочли документацию и все ли условия соблюдены? http://wiki.webmoney.ru/projects/webmoney/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_X2

Comment: Вроде бы нет, спасибо! буду пробовать

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо на странице https://merchant.webmoney.ru/conf/purses.asp включить интерфейс X2 и всё заработает!